# calling a python module that impors openpyxl from php

Tags: php, python, import, openpyxl

I have a python module that imports openpyxl:

```
import openpyxl  
print("xlsupload.py")
```

It works at command prompt in windows when I run:

```
"python.exe python\xlsm_upload.py"
```

Then I tried calling this module in php:

```
    $cmd = escapeshellcmd('python.exe python\xlsm_upload.py');
    $result = exec($cmd, $output, $status);
```

The `$status` returns `1` and nothing in `$output`.
When I comment out the statement "`import openpyxl`", it works fine.

It seems that "`import openpyxl`" works at command prompt but not when `exec()` in php.  Any suggestions?  Many many thanks.

Comment: In my experience `exec` and `system` are not great at returning output. Try using `proc_open`. It's a little bit more difficult to set up; you need to configure the pipes; but I've found it to be more reliable. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Comment: Eek! PHP calling Python! Hazmat equipment required! ;-) Rather than trying to read stdout you might want your test script to do something like write a file that you can check or write to syslog.